# How can I allocate 16K continuous memory in kernel and get the physical address?

Tags: linux-kernel

My understand is kernel page size is 4K. I want to allocate 16K continuous memory as my buffer for my driver. I used kmalloc() and it returns me a pointer (I assume the allocation is successful).

Does that mean the 16K is continuous?

And is the address I get from kmalloc() a virtual address? If I need to pass that address to a HW register, do I use a virtual address or a physical address?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - memory allocated with kmalloc is physically continous and the address is virtual address. Try virt_to_phys() macro to obtain physical address.

Comment: But why the return value of virt_to_phys() is same as what I input (the value I got from kmalloc)?

Comment: It is working for me: kmalloc() addr: 0xc3c0a000 and virt_to_phys() for it is: 0x3c0a000. I've got XScale-435 processor. As far as I know on Intel x86 it is working same - just by substracting PAGE_OFFSET (0xc0000000 for my systems) value from kmalloc() addr.